How do I use ChatGPT plugin in JavaScript?
I tried to import ChatGPT into my js project to use it lately in HTML, but the response is empty. I want to use it to generate random stories. Do you know what might cause this?
const form = 0;
const mytextInput = 0;
const responseTextarea = 0;

function dok(){
    form = document.getElementById(`chat-form`);
    mytextInput = document.getElementById('mytext');
    responseTextarea = document.getElementById('response');
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response;
}


const API_KEY = "sk-proj-d127W0pgdYpbW6uDRaUvT3BlbkFJ90Q1QFAuCi7UMkxxES8P";
const response = "";

async function generate()   {
    const mytext = mytextInput.value.trim();
    const mytext2 = "hello"
    if (mytext2) {
        try {
            response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    model: 'gpt-4o',
                    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: mytext }],
                    temperature: 1.0,
                    top_p: 0.7,
                    n: 1,
                    stream: false,
                    presence_penalty: 0,
                    frequency_penalty: 0,
                }),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                responseTextarea.value = data.choices[0].message.content;
                
            } else {
                responseTextarea.value = 'Error: Unable to process your request.';
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            responseTextarea.value = 'Error: Unable to process your request.';
        }
    }
};

I tried to completely rewrite it, use YouTube tutorials, but nothing worked and when I finally fixed all the errors in the code.
npm run dev

> scripts@1.0.0 dev
> node skript1.js





Welcome to StackOverflow! I would recommend reconsidering the approach, because if what you are building is going to be used publicly, your OpenAI API key is exposed on the front end. You should have a backend server that makes the request to OpenAI and let your frontend make requests to your server. Also, I highly recommend removing your API key from your post because others might steal it and start charging money on your OpenAI account!

Indeed, you've exposed your API key to the entire world now; you should consider cancelling that one and getting a new one.

There are a couple of issues that might be causing the empty response:
Initialization:
In your dok function, you're assigning the result of document.getElementById to constant variables (form, mytextInput, responseTextarea) but these variables are already set to 0. Change the assignment to capture the actual DOM elements.

Empty Prompt:
In your generate function, you have a conditional statement that checks if mytext2 (which is set to "hello") exists. If it doesn't exist, the code skips the fetch request entirely. This means if the user types something in the mytextInput field, it won't be used as the prompt because mytext2 will always be truthy ("hello" is not empty).

At the very least, check your console for errors.

const form = document.getElementById(`chat-form`);
const mytextInput = document.getElementById('mytext');
const responseTextarea = document.getElementById('response');

const API_KEY = "XXX";
let response = "";

async function generate() {
  const mytext = mytextInput.value.trim(); // Get user input from mytextInput

  if (mytext) { // Check if user input exists
    try {
      response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          model: 'gpt-4o',
          messages: [{ role: 'user', content: mytext }],
          temperature: 1.0,
          top_p: 0.7,
          n: 1,
          stream: false,
          presence_penalty: 0,
          frequency_penalty: 0,
        }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        responseTextarea.value = data.choices[0].message.content;
      } else {
        responseTextarea.value = 'Error: Unable to process your request.';
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      responseTextarea.value = 'Error: Unable to process your request.';
    }
  } else {
    responseTextarea.value = "Please enter a starting prompt."; // Inform user to enter text
  }
};

This code should now:

Get the DOM elements correctly in the beginning.
Use the user's input (mytext) as the prompt for the ChatGPT API call.
Provide feedback to the user if they haven't entered any text.


I tried it but it says, that "ReferenceError: document is not defined".

The "ReferenceError: document is not defined" error you're encountering when using the ChatGPT API in your JavaScript project indicates that the code is trying to access the document object, which is specific to web browsers, in a non-browser environment.

If you're trying to run the code on the server-side (e.g., Node.js), you can't directly use the document object. Consider alternative libraries or services that work in server-side environments.
